# Is there a way to see the full signature of functions in an unmanaged dll like user32.dll , kernel32.dll?

Tags: c#, winapi, dll, unmanaged

I know I can see a list of functions inside the dll by using `dumpbin /exports [filename]`.

Is there a way to see the signature of these functions (what parameters I need to invoke it)?

Comment: No.  You need the various Windows H files to see those.  Unmanaged code doesn't carry metadata around like .NET DLLs do.  If you are calling things from C# (as your tags would indicate), take a look at http://pinvoke.net.  You should be able to get enough information to call just about any standard DLL athere

Comment: From dumpbin, no. From the MS documentation, yes.

Comment: @fly: That's incorrect. Function signatures carry varying amounts of metadata. A decorated C++ function signature encodes the entire list of argument types. That statement, that *"unmanaged code doesn't carry metadata around like .NET DLLs"* if false.

Comment: You could also try the [winsiggen](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/CLRInsideOut2008_01.exe) tool. Worked good for me in the past, don't know if it is still current.

Comment: Yes. Look in the documentation and header files. The former is important. Knowing the types of the parameters is seldom enough to be able to call a function. You need to know the semantics, and understand the interface contract.

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes C++ decorated functions carry metadata around in their decorated names (though the decoration is not standardized, AFAIK).  However, the OP asked about DLLs *"like user32.dll , kernel32.dll"*.  All of those DLLs have `export c` calls and the only decoration they carry is the STDCALL decoration (which tells you the number of bytes of parameters used by the call - again, from memory)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan where can I see the header files?

Comment: The header files are found in the Windows SDK. They aren't enough though. You need to read the documentation. Have you?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to official documents: [winuser.h header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/) and [processthreadsapi.h header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/) for lists of functions in user32.dll and kernel32.dll.

For the signature of one specified function click the function name you will be directed to its document where you can find almost all about the function.